# Why can't I display a svg file on the screen?

Tags: angular, browser, plugins

My project is written with Angular and .net.
I'm trying to display a svg file on the screen with the following code:

```
<div class="col-2">
  <object
     id="svg1"
     data="D:\src\assets\airplane1.svg"
     type="svg+xml">
  </object>
</div>
```

The code is OK ang going without errors, no issues also on the browser when I run it.
But at the screen on the browser- instead of watching the file- google alerts with the following message: "This plugin is not supported" (with a small icon with a piece of puzzle).
I tried it also on Microsoft-Edge and Firefox but it all the same.
What can it be?

Comment: `<object>` always has been kinda messy, why not using an `<img>` tag instead? This might help [Best way to embed svg](https://vecta.io/blog/best-way-to-embed-svg)

Answer (score 0):

Move (or copy) the image to `src/assets` and use the path assets/airplane1.svg. This is the normal way. You can convert the SVG to base64 type.

```
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use img tag instead of object, then the code would be much simpler, If you are having svg in your angular project's src, you can provide the path in img tag as follows. It will work fine

```
<img src="./assets/airplane1.svg" id="svg1" />
```